# How to create a comment to an oracle database view

Tags: oracle, view, code-documentation

I would really like to create a comment to a view with a short description of its purpose. Unfortunately it is not possible to create comments to views in oracle. This feature is only for tables, columns and materialized views available. I would like to know how you do describe your database views?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```sql
comment on table <name> is 'text';
```

The command works on views. For example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_VW AS
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

COMMENT ON TABLE MY_VW IS 'Clever comment.';
```

Answer (score 5):

Its possible to create a comment on VIEWs too :

```
COMMENT ON TABLE view_name ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use :

```
Comment on table 'view Name' is  ' Comment ...';
```

If use view in place of SQL , Oracle throws error invalid object category for COMMENT command".

Materialized  View  :  we can simply comment using:

```
Command on Materialized view "View name" is  'Comment ...';
```